# Toggle column display in ASP.NET gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have two email fields, one a text field (index 15), the other a mailto: hyperlink (index 16), both in a gridview. (And yes, I know identifying via index isn't the best way to go -- just trying to make it work at this point).

When not editing, I need to show only the hyperlink field (making it available for the user to click on). When editing, I need to show only the text field, so they can modify the value.

I've got everything working as needed **except** that both fields display when the grid is initially shown. If I try to hide the text field in any of the normal ways (hiding cells on RowDataBound or hiding the column upon declaration), then it doesn't show up when editing.

Here's what I'm doing so far. The RowEditing event has the following code:

```
 GridView1.Columns(16).Visible = False
 GridView1.Columns(15).Visible = True
```

The RowCancelingEdit event has the opposite logic, toggling visibility on both fields. And finally the RowUpdating event has the following, which turns the hyperlink display back on:

```
GridView1.Columns(16).Visible = True
```

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET, so I definitely don't know all of the constructs available.

How can I hide the text field upon normal grid display, but still have the field available to show when in edit mode?

Comment: I'd rather display / hide the components in one columns depending if you are editing or not rather than hiding displaying columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It dawned on me that I could simply show/hide columns upon the initial databind (which works), as such:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        DataBind()
        GridView1.Columns(16).Visible = True
        GridView1.Columns(15).Visible = False
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to RowCommand  Event and set Edit button CommandName="name"

```
If e.CommandName = "name" Then
 Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
Dim lblwwwhid = CType(row.FindControl("txtwwwhid"), Label)
lblwwwhid .visible =false
End if
```